# Set (Sigma) Symbol as custom button text in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using `Highcharts` for plotting the chart.
In my chart I want to use custom button and for that purpose I am using `exporting` module of Highcharts.

I used below option to add custom button into the chart.

```
exporting: {
   buttons: {
      contextButton: {
          enabled: false
      },
      customButton: {
          onclick: function () {
            alert('Clicked');
          },
          text: '&#931;',
            x: -62
          }
     }
}
```

I am seeing the custom button on chart but its text is `&#931;`
But I want to set the text of button as **Sigma (Σ)** found [here](http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html)

```
&Sigma; = Σ &#931;  = Σ greek capital letter sigma, U+03A3 ISOgrk3
```

I tried to use code as text but its not working.

Can anybody help me to get it work ?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F4pJ/339/).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use letter, instead of entity.

```
text: "Σ",
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2F4pJ/341/